firebase-firestore-24.11.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog
When I am trying to run the application to the android emulator , this problem is showing.enter image description here
I want the solve of this problem. I do not know how to solve this problem. This problem is occouring everytime when I am trying to run the application to the emulator. Please Help.
Error that is showing in below :
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
[Fatal Error] firebase-firestore-24.11.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] firebase-firestore-24.11.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.11.0.
Required by:
project :app > project :cloud_firestore
> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.11.0.
> Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-firestore/24.11.0/firebase-firestore-24.11.0.pom
> Content is not allowed in prolog.
> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.11.0.
> Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-firestore/24.11.0/firebase-firestore-24.11.0.pom
> Content is not allowed in prolog.
Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.11.0.
Required by:
project :app > project :firebase_core > com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0
> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.11.0.
> Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-firestore/24.11.0/firebase-firestore-24.11.0.pom
> Content is not allowed in prolog.
> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.11.0.
> Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-firestore/24.11.0/firebase-firestore-24.11.0.pom
> Content is not allowed in prolog.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Can you copy the error text into the question body?

I have added the error text.

When I am adding cloud_firestore package this error is occouring.
